# Using fgets(char* c, int i, file* f) with printf() for C in Eclipse - CDT. The order of output is not correct.!

Tags: c, eclipse, printf, fgets, eclipse-cdt

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum { max_string = 127 };
static char ch[max_string+1] = "";

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    printf("Type a String: \n");
    fgets(ch, max_string, stdin);
    printf("the string is: %s", ch);
    return 0;
}
```

I have used this code and the output in the console was

```
hello world
Type a String: 
the string is: hello world
```

'hello world' is the input which I give.

My question is why isn't the order not maintained in this case. As printf() should work before fgets(), but here it isn't that way. I have checked with the same compiler in Code::Blocks. There it works in order.
But in case of Eclipse-MARS CDT I find it erroneous.

Comment: Are you saying the `"Type a string: "` prompt did not appear until after you typed `"hello world"` and pressed enter?

Comment: yes you got it right! @TomKarzes

Comment: That is very odd.  Normally I would say to add a newline after the prompt, but it looks like you already have it.  I would add one to the other printf as well, but of course that doesn't explain it.  One suggestion though:  Try adding `fflush(stdout);` right before the call to `fgets`, i.e. after printing the prompt.  See if that fixes it.

Comment: unrelated : It should be `fgets(ch, sizeof ch, stdin);`

Comment: Thank you very much @TomKarzes fflush(stdout) soved the problem. But why is that necessary? I was following a tutorial where they did the program without fflush(stdout). But it doesn't work in my case!!

Comment: Ok well `fflush` is kind of guaranteed to solve it.  It tells the stdio library to completely flush the stream you give it (in this case, `stdout`).  The reason I was surprised is normally `stdout` is "line buffered" when associated with a "terminal" (as opposed to a file).  This means that it will buffer up to a newline, but when it sees a newline it flushes it.  This tends to work well for interactive output.  For a prompt with no newline, you can call `fflush` to force it to print.  But in your case, it seems it wasn't being line buffered, since you had a newline in the prompt.

Comment: Most likely, in the context of Eclipse CDT, the standard output is not considered to be an 'interactive device' (terminal), so the standard output is not automatically flushed before the input operation.  Typically, when standard output is a terminal, then reading from standard input triggers a flush of standard output, so that prompts are displayed, etc.  But this is not guaranteed by the standard; putting the explicit `fflush(stdout)` before the input operation ensures that the output is flushed as you want and expect.

Comment: Yes that surprises me too. It is only the case with Eclipse CDT. Using the same compiler suite the program ran as it should've in Code:Blocks. This problem is with Eclipse I guess, can't find a solution to it except using fflush(stdout)

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile (however that is not the root of your problem)  When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  The posted code raises two warnings 1) unused parameter: argc. 2) unused parameter: argv.  This can be fixed by using one of the other valid main() signatures,  I.E. `int main( void )`

Comment: The root of the problem must be in `eclipse` as the posted code works very nicely when run on ubuntu linux from a command prompt.

Comment: yes I am confirmed that the problem is with eclipse and specially in my machine. I have followed the same code in another machine using eclipse - indigo, there it works without any use of fflush(stdout). Can anyone suggest me a workaround possibly a change in eclipse settings that'd make the console interactive as proposed by @JonathanLeffler.

Comment: @user3629249 the posted code also ran in my machine using the same compiler without any issues I have with eclipse.

Comment: @user3629249 I am passing command line arguments to the program. I have done this from the properties of the project->Run/Debug Settings->Selecting the project I am working on and editing it.->In the arguments tab gave arguments. Doing this gave no warning for me. However, this is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're running on Windows, and running into a [longstanding problem](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732)  with console output in Eclipse CDT on Windows.

The bug is marked as "WONTFIX", and the comments explain why it's a hard problem to fix. They do suggest several workarounds:

- Call `fflush(stdout)` after each call to `printf`. This flushes the output buffer explicitly after each output operation.
- Call `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` once at the beginning of your program. This disables output buffering altogether.
- Use CDT's experimental "winpty" support as described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173732#c43). This attempts to make Eclipse's console have the same behaviour as a real terminal, including line buffering.

I have a much simpler solution to suggest: **build** your program with Eclipse, but **run** it directly from a terminal (Command Prompt). Then you will get proper terminal behaviour without any workarounds.