# Why Ecplise (CDT) console and debug don't work properly?

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have the following problem with a C code in Eclipse. This is the minimal code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char inputch[20];
    fgets(inputch,20,stdin);
    printf("%s", inputch);
    getchar();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code is built correctly and if I run it from the built .exe, it works properly: I write a line and press ENTER, then the line entered is showed in the console and then if I press any button in the keyboard the console shutdown.
But the behaviour is different if I run the program in the "run mode of eclipse": when I write the line and I type ENTER, nothing happen; when I type ENTER once again, the line I wrote before appears in the console and the program ends. If I wrote something between the first and the second ENTER, this line doesn't appear in the stamp; however, the stamp appear always at the second ENTER typing, the same that ends the programs, like the getchar and the printf are inverted.
The second problem is in debug mode: if I try to debug the code, if I put a breakpoint in the fgets() function and try to step into, the debug console doesn't permit me to write the entry in the STDIO, but step immediatly at the next statement.

MY CONFIGURATION: eclipse Neon 3 4.6.3 x64, CDT, Cygwin compipler x64, windows 8.1 64 bit
EDIT: I tried also with miniGW but the problem persist. The debugger, in both case, is GDB 7.6.11

Comment: try `printf("%s", inputch);fflush(stdout);`

Comment: it worked, thank you. But doesn't solve the problem with the debug (I don't think it is intended to do it anyway). Thank you!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43160445/141719) for more details about the first problem. I'm not sure about the debug issue.