# Eclipse cdt no output on console; MinGW Path is already set

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm sure you guys have gotten sick of seeing this question over and over again by now but none of the solutions displayed in the other threads have worked for me. I've tried setting the C:\MinGW Path variable, the linker flags, nothing works.
The only thing that has worked is adding:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

to the code but I really do not want to keep writing this in every single program I make.

The console does show the red "Terminate" button as active so that at least means that the program is running but just not being displayed in the console.

To those not familiar with this bug; I wrote a simple C program in eclipse:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it the console looks like this:
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IGzN.png)

And output is:

```
5
Enter number: 0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Any ideas?

Also I'm running Windows 10, maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using fgets(char\* c, int i, file\* f) with printf() for C in Eclipse - CDT. The order of output is not correct.!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604947/using-fgetschar-c-int-i-file-f-with-printf-for-c-in-eclipse-cdt-the-o)

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43160445/141719).

Comment: So no solid solution? Funny because I do remember that eclipse cdt used to work fine in windows 7. It's just on windows 10 that it's bring this fussy.