# Simple C program not showing output in eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

A few days back I installed Eclipse ide and also the CDT plugin therein for C and C++ development. Also made the necessary settings. Also tried a simple C program of adding two integers. Surprisingly, no output was shown in the terminal, but when the program was terminated it showed a wrong output of `0`.

The program was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a, b;
  printf("Enter an integer: "); scanf("%d", &a);
  printf("Enter another integer: "); scanf("%d", &b);
  printf("Sum = %d", (a+b));
  return 0;
}
```

This same program showed the correct output when it was ran using the command prompt:

```
 gcc -g add.c -o add.exe
```

Have I made any mistake in the code? Can anyone suggest me what do I need to do to run it in Wclipse?

Comment: You can try to compile directly with gcc for instance to see if is some syntactically error. If you try that you see that your short program is correct.

Comment: You're probably running into the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604947/using-fgetschar-c-int-i-file-f-with-printf-for-c-in-eclipse-cdt-the-o/43160445). Please see my answer there.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: Always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `printf("Sum = %d", (a+b));`  stream I/O is buffered.  So, currently, the data is not pushed to the terminal until the program exits.  To correct that problem, use the format string: `"Sum = %d\n"`   Note the trailing newline sequence, which causes the stdout stream to be flushed to the terminal.,

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: Tried every piece of your advises, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

have you build the project in the first place?
Go to "Project" tab in main tool bar and click on build project. If successful setup up a new run configuration for C under "Run" tab. And in the C/C++ application field -> "Search Project" and choose your project's binary from the list.

Now try running your custom run/debug configuration.